# Cannot access localhost from any browser

Tags: localhost, windows-10

I cannot access localhost from either Chrome or IE.  I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in Chrome.  I went into my settings and clicked the option to bypass proxy for local addresses and that didn't work.  I'm running Windows 10.

Thanks.

Comment: What sort of web server is listening on `localhost`?

Comment: You need to supply more information about what you're trying to do. That error generally means that the browser cannot connect to a web server on the host and port you have specified. Do you have a web server running on your computer? What port is it running on? What does it do?

Comment: To see what is running, run `netstat -a` on a command prompt. You will get a list of sockets in use.

Comment: ARE YOU USING SOME SORT OF ENVIRONMENT?

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggestion..

Try to check what port your apache is connected to. If you have other applications running or installed and using the same port, then try to change and listen to other port. If you are using xampp, you can change the port by clicking config in apache and edit 80 to 81. You may then write your url as localhost:81 when browsing.